# Interactive map in Excel macro

Tags: excel, freeform, vba

I am having troubles with the coding above "9".

```
              Sub ColourStates()

Dim intState As Integer
Dim strStateName As String
Dim intStateValue As Integer
Dim intColourLookup As Integer
Dim rngStates As Range
Dim rngColours As Range

Set rngStates = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("STATES").RefersTo)
Set rngColours = Range(ThisWorkbook.Names("STATE_COLOURS").RefersTo)

With Worksheets("MainMap")
    For intState = 1 To rngStates.Rows.Count
        strStateName = rngStates.Cells(intState, 1).Text
        intStateValue = rngStates.Cells(intState, 2).Value


            ' single colour
            intColourLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(intStateValue, Range("STATE_COLOURS"), True)
            With .Shapes(strStateName)
                .Fill.Solid
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rngColours.Cells(intColourLookup, 1).Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color
            End With

    Next
End With
```

End Sub

Here is the link to the file itself: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/MapOfStates.xls

It works fine for values below 9, but I need it to work until 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array STATE_COLORS includes only values within 0 to 9 interval. Here are the steps you need to proceed with:
1) open excel file
2) go to Formulas Tag
3) click on the Name Manager
4) choose STATE_COLORS arrays
5) increase the values to 20

Get back to me if you have any other questions.